# If statement inside for loop Java

Tags: java

I wanna know where I went wrong with my logic. I want to entire the for loop when found == true and do the condition else if not found i wanna execute that condition. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
boolean found = false;

for (String keyword : keywords) {
    found = true;
    if (input.contains(keyword)) {
        parseFile(keyword);
        break;
    }
    if (!found) {
        Writer();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand what you want

Comment: Why do you make `found = true;` for each keyword. This will stay true for all the cases.

Comment: I do not understand. You're saying I should set found = true instead of found = false ?

Comment: No @Eggz you must change that by a method. By checking. Otherwise it will stay the same for all the cases.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but it sounds like you want to loop through your keywords and if the keyword is found, you want to run your first condition and leave the for loop. Then if none of the keywords match, you want to do the final condition. If so, this should match what you are looking for:

```
boolean found = false;
for (String keyword : keywords) 
{
    if (input.contains(keyword)) 
    {
        found = true;
        parseFile(keyword);
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) 
{
    Writer();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want to change `found` based on the `if` test in the loop. Like,

```
// found = true;
if (input.contains(keyword)) {
    found = true; // <-- otherwise it doesn't make sense.
```

since you then test

```
if (!found) { // <-- can only evaluate to true if found is false.
```

Also, I think that's supposed to be after you loop. Something like,

```
for (String keyword : keywords) {
    if (input.contains(keyword)) {
        found = true;
        parseFile(keyword);
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    Writer();
}
```

Comment: for (String keyword : keywords) {
    if (input.contains(keyword)) {
        found = true;
        parseFile(keyword);
        break;
    } 
}

if (!found) {
    Writer(); 
    break;
}

Comment: @PrashantKhaire No `break` needed outside the for loop.

Comment: if the keyword is not found the second if statement is skipped. I do not know for what reason

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `found = true` outside the first `if` statement, so you will never enter the `if (!found)` block. Instead, you might want to set it up like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for (String keyword : keywords) {
    if (input.contains(keyword)) {
        found = true;
        parseFile(keyword);
        break;
    } 
}

if (!found) {
    Writer(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `found = true;` outside of your `if` statement, you erase any chance of `found` being `false`.

In other words, you've set `found` to `true` and nowhere in your code do you create a condition where `found` switches to `false`, so it will stay `true` This makes your entire `if (!found)` block is useless.
You need to set `found` to true outside the `for` loop